# Alternate multiple columns in an html table with php

Tags: php, dynamic, alternate

How can I output an alternate multiple column like this

```
<table border="1">
    <tr> 
        <td> userid 1 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
        <td> userid 2</td> <td>userid 3 </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr> 
        <td> userid 4 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td> userid5 </td> <td>userid6 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td> userid7 </td> 
        <td>userid8 </td>
        <td> userid9 </td> 
        <td>userid10</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<br>
<table border=1>
```

My table query is like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM  `tbl-record`") or die(mysql_error());
```

Classic example in action is like this:

```
http://www.cashcashpinoy.com
```

A table with five rows and an alternate 1x2x1x2x4 columns (TD ) on each rows ( TR )

Answer (score 1):

Since this is in a table, you can use the `colspan` attribute on the `td` elements, like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Full width data.</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Half width data.</td>
    <td colspan="2">Half width data.</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">Quarter width data.</td>
    <td colspan="1">Quarter width data.</td>
    <td colspan="1">Quarter width data.</td>
    <td colspan="1">Quarter width data.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can do this with any number of columns.

If you want to assign a number of columns dynamically, you'll want to have a set number of results to provide some consistency, which you could do using a `LIMIT` along with your query.

```
$results; // This is all of the results of your query
$colOps = array(1,2,4); // Different colspan values
$numCols = 4; // Maximum columns to allow per line

echo '<table border="1">';
while(count($results) > 0) {
  $ind = mt_rand(0, 2); // Generate a random index number
  if(count($results) >= $colOps[$ind]) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for($i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++)
      echo '<td colspan="'.$colOps[$ind].'">'.array_shift($results).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
}
echo '</table>';
```

Note that this is untested and may need some modification to work properly.

Comment: for one item this is the only one i got  `echo '<table border=1>';
  foreach (array_chunk($m, 1) as $row)
  { 
   echo'   <tr>';
     foreach ($row as $value) 
     { 
         echo '<td>'.htmlentities($value).'</td> ';
      } 
  echo'    </tr>';
   
 }
 echo '</table>';` how can i do this for 1x2x1x2x4 columns (TD ) on each rows ( TR ). say for instance for tr1 theres 1td, for tr2 theres 2td and so on ?